# Laravel get Selected Value with Variable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to get the select value which also happens to be a variable is that possible if not how can I get that done.

```
<select name="foo">
    <option value="bar"></option>
</select>
echo Input::get('foo'); // outputs bar
```

How can I get this work?

```
<select name="foo">
    <option value="{{$bar->first}}"></option>
</select>
<echo Input::get('foo') // outputs nothing
```

Comment: Did you forget to put a `$` in front of your variable?

Comment: Sorry had a typo , I do have the $ sign but get nothing in return

Comment: Can you show the code that sets the `$bar` variable?

Answer (score 0):

```
Change <option value="{{bar1}}"></option> to
<option value="{{$bar1}}"></option>
```

Comment: Thanks that happens to be how it looks like. Sorry for the typo

Comment: Please check $bar->first has value.

Comment: It does because I use it. What I have an issue now is how to get it back

Comment: @tagnihuguespascal, please show how you are setting the `$bar` variable ?